# Retrieving all values from a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

This is the function I wrote to retrieve all the values in an given object.

```
function getValues(data){
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    var values = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = keys.length, key; i< l; i++){
        key = keys[i];
        values.push(data[key]);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Is there any builtin way to retrieve all the values in an object? Something like this exists in java for HashMaps. I know JS has a method for retrieving all the keys by doing `Object.keys(obj)`.

Comment: `for..in` seems more suitable for objects.

Comment: if you are using underscore - there is a `values` function.

Comment: Not in plain JavaScript, but it's simple to make.

Comment: No.  There is no built in way to do what you asked.

Comment: @squint, thx for review, corrected coding mistakes, for values, you are right, but for key, it is defined in for loop...

Comment: Deleted since you updated, though you could drop the `key` variable now  since it's only used once. `data[keys[i]]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the most concise way of getting an array of the values contained within an object is to use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
};
values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
    return obj[key];
});
```

Otherwise there's no standardized way of getting an array of an object's values.

For iterating, ES6 introduces a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop which will iterate through an object's values:

<sub>continued from above:</sub>

```
for (value of obj) {
    console.log(value); //1, 2, 3
}
```

ES7 is slated to introduce [array comprehensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), so generating the values array could be written as:

<sub>continued from above:</sub>

```
values = [for (x of Object.keys(obj)) obj[x]];
```

If you're already using underscore, you can use the [`_.values`](http://underscorejs.org/#values) method:

<sub>continued from above:</sub>

```
_.values(obj); //[1, 2, 3]
```

If you just want an efficient implementation for this utility function, the [lodash source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/2.4.1/dist/lodash.js) is:

<sub>lodash.js v2.4.1 lines 2891-2914</sub>

```
/**
 * Creates an array composed of the own enumerable property values of `object`.
 *
 * @static
 * @memberOf _
 * @category Objects
 * @param {Object} object The object to inspect.
 * @returns {Array} Returns an array of property values.
 * @example
 *
 * _.values({ 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 });
 * // => [1, 2, 3] (property order is not guaranteed across environments)
 */
function values(object) {
  var index = -1,
      props = keys(object),
      length = props.length,
      result = Array(length);

  while (++index < length) {
    result[index] = object[props[index]];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Another ES6 possibility: `[for (x of Object.keys(obj)) obj[x]]`

Comment: @squint, wouldn't it just be `[for (x of obj) x]`?

Comment: I don't know if that's planned. I'm just testing in FF right now, and it tells me that it's a syntax error. And with `[for (x of obj) x]` it tells me that `obj` isn't an iterator. Do you know if it's going to be?

Comment: What a lovely, in-depth, well formatted answer. Kudos to you, sir.

Comment: It's worth noting that Array comprehensions [have been removed from the ES6 proposal in August](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#august_24_2014_draft_rev_27) and are now apparently planned to be included in ES7.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, in newer Browsers:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'values', {
  get:function(){
    return function(o){
      var a = [];
      for(var i in o){
        a.push(o[i]);
      }
      return a;
    }
  }
});
var arrayOfValues = Object.values({a:'A',b:'B',c:'C'});
```

Really, I would just do:

```
function objectValues(obj, inherited){
  var a = [];
  for(var i in obj){
    var v = obj[i];
    if(inherited){
      a.push(v);
    }
    else if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      a.push(v);
    }
  }
  return a;
}
var notInheritedArrayOfValues = objectValues({a:'A',b:'B',c:'C'});
var inheritedArrayOfValues = objectValues({a:'A',b:'B',c:'C'}, true);
```